# Running Selenium on Firefox 15

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run Selenium 2.5 on Firefox 15.0.1 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using python2. I am trying to run the following python script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

I get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: "Can't load the profile
```

Looking through the code, the fails within the is_connectable() method at line:

```
socket_.connect(("127.0.0.1", self.profile.port))
```

I receive the following error:

```
error: (111, 'Connection refused')
```

According to the comment under the method, the method "Trys to connect to the extension but do not retrieve context." Reading from previous posts it does not seem like I need to install a geckodriver (needed for Firefox 47+ and Selenium 3).

Comment: Fixed my own problem. Just upgrade selenium to 2.53.6

Answer (score 0):

Just upgrade selenium to 2.53.6

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).